# Monitor an area of the screen for a certain color in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, screen-scraping

I'm designing a player application to accompany our phone system.  As our calltakers take calls, it makes recordings of each call.  They can go to a list module, find a recording and double click, which opens my player.  The issue i have is that if the calltaker gets another call, my player doesn't know it and will continue playing.  I'm looking for a way to monitor the screen in a particular area and when it sees yellow or red instead of blue, it will pause my player.

The phone system does not have any API's that I can hook onto, so I have to try it another way.

The screen resolution never changes and the queue buttons where they receive calls will always be static.  When they get a call, a small area changes from the background color blue to yellow or red to indicate a call.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT
Final Code based on answers below and question [Memory Leak using GetPixel/GetDC in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10048733/832563)

```
Private Function CheckforCall()
    Dim hDC As IntPtr = GetDC(0)
    Try
        Dim queue1 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 40, 573)
        Dim queue2 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 140, 573)
        Dim queue3 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 240, 573)
        Dim queue4 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 340, 573)
        Dim queue5 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 440, 573)

        If queue1 <> 9990727 Then
            lblRinger.Text = "In Calls GOT CALL"
            Return True
        ElseIf queue2 <> 9990727 Then
            lblRinger.Text = "Admin GOT CALL"
            Return True
        ElseIf queue3 <> 9990727 Then
            lblRinger.Text = "Overflow GOT CALL"
            Return True
        ElseIf queue4 <> 9990727 Then
            lblRinger.Text = "Bi-Lingual GOT CALL"
            Return True
        ElseIf queue5 <> 9990727 Then
            lblRinger.Text = "Intercom GOT CALL"
            Return True
        Else
            lblRinger.Text = "No Call"
            Return False
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    Finally
        ReleaseDC(0, hDC)
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28257727/4515800

Got your answer, riiiiiiiight here Geezzer ;) ^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @@@@@@@@@@@@


Answered BELOW

http://stackoverflow.com/a/28257727/4515800



@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is what you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx

Good luck!

EDIT:

I forgot you have to give a device context (`hDC`) to have `GetPixel` work. It's sometimes hard to deal with the window handles (`hWnd`) that `GetDC` requires, so you can simply get the device context for the entire screen with `GetDC(0)`.

Code shamelessly stolen from http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=491397 :

```
Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32" ( _
  ByVal lpClassName As String, _
  ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hdc As IntPtr) As IntPtr

Private Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal X As Int32, ByVal Y As Int32) As Int32

Public Function GetColorAt(ByVal X As Int32, ByVal Y As Int32) As Int32

    Dim hWnd As IntPtr
    Dim hDC As IntPtr

    hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "RagII")

    hDC = GetDC(hWnd)

    Dim lColor As Int32 = GetPixel(hDC, X, Y)  

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC)

    Return lColor
End Function
```

Comment: I've gotten a test application running with a form of the other code presented on that website.  That example allows you to move the mouse around and it grabs the pixel color of the cursor position. I modified it to check 5 pixels.  Integrating into my player now.  I will post the proper code when I've got it working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PrintWindow` function from the Win32 API to get the bitmap for a specific window. You can then read the pixels from this bitmap with `Bitmap.GetPixel`:

You need to import this (and probably more functions) using `DllImport`:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function PrintWindow(hwnd As IntPtr, hdcBlt As IntPtr, nFlags As UInteger) As Boolean
```

Here is a small sample code to capture a window:

```
Using bm As New Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
    Dim hdc As IntPtr = g.GetHdc()
    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, 0) 'hwnd is the window handle of the phone application
    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc)
    g.Flush()
    Return Image.FromHbitmap(bm.GetHbitmap())
End Using
```

**However:** Try to see if there really isn't another way to solve this. Capturing the screen will be a fragile solution which is only waiting to break in the next update of the calling software.