# Memory Leak using GetPixel/GetDC in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, screen-scraping

I have a timer that among other things, checks 5 spots on the screen for a color change.  My program monitors a phone system app and checks to see if there is a new incoming phone call from any of 5 buttons.  I'm using the following code based on another question I had posted.  [Monitor an area of the screen for a certain color in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10035140/832563)

```
Private Function CheckforCall()
    Try
        Dim queue1 As Integer = GetPixel(GetDC(0), 40, 573)
        Dim queue2 As Integer = GetPixel(GetDC(0), 140, 573)
        Dim queue3 As Integer = GetPixel(GetDC(0), 240, 573)
        Dim queue4 As Integer = GetPixel(GetDC(0), 340, 573)
        Dim queue5 As Integer = GetPixel(GetDC(0), 440, 573)
        ReleaseDC(0)

    <code snipped - Checks to see if the pixel color matches and 
       returns true or false>

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Using this code, GDI Objects skyrockets very quickly and within short order, throws an OutOfMemory exception.  I'm assuming I'm not releasing the DC properly, but I can't seem to find any other way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `GetDC(0)` once, save it to a variable, and pass the variable to `ReleaseDC`:

```
Dim hDC As IntPtr = GetDC(0)
Try
    Dim queue1 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 40, 573)
    Dim queue2 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 140, 573)
    Dim queue3 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 240, 573)
    Dim queue4 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 340, 573)
    Dim queue5 As Integer = GetPixel(hDC, 440, 573)
    ...
Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
Finally
    ReleaseDC(0, hDC)
End Try
```

Note that [`ReleaseDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162920.aspx) takes two `IntPtr` arguments, `hWnd` and `hDC`.

Comment: Also, put the ReleaseDC in a finally block, so it's cleaned up even on exception.

Comment: Finally, not Catch. Now it won't clean up in the normal path. :-)

Comment: @MichaelLiu That did the trick!  Thank you!  My app detects calls and no memory leak!