# Trying to get pixel color from screen coordinates, cant call my function

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get the pixel color for set screen coordinates. I have a function I found and for some reason I can not call it. I placed it into a new class and I am trying to call it from my main form although it is not recognizing the function. It is a public class and a public function so I am not sure why. Thanks.

```
    #Region "#include"
    Imports System
    Imports System.Drawing
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
    #End Region
    Public Class Test

    #Region "From Windows API"
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function GetWindowDC(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
   'Do not try to name this method "GetDC" it will say that user32 doesnt have GetDC !!!
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function ReleaseDC(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hdc As IntPtr) As Int32

End Function

<DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function GetPixel(ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal nXPos As Integer, ByVal nYPos As Integer) As UInteger

End Function
#End Region
REM --Test--
#Region "Some Functions"
Public Function GetPixelColor(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Color
    Dim hdc As IntPtr = GetWindowDC(IntPtr.Zero)
    Dim pixel As UInteger = GetPixel(hdc, x, y)
    Dim color As Color
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc)
    MsgBox(pixel)
    color = color.FromArgb(Int(pixel And &HFF), _
    Int(pixel And &HFF00) >> 8, _
    Int(pixel And &HFF0000) >> 16)
    Return color
End Function
#End Region
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you would either need to create an instance of that class:

```
Dim t As New Test
Dim pc As Color = t.GetPixelColor(20, 20)
```

Or make that function a Public Shared Function, then you would not need an instance of test:

```
Dim pc As Color = test.GetPixelColor(20, 20)
```

Alternately you could just take a screengrab and use the built in [bitmap.GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) and avoid that class all together:

```
   Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

    Using screenGrab As New Bitmap(My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width, My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height)

        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)

            g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, 0), screenSize)

            Dim pc As Color = screenGrab.GetPixel(20, 20)
        End Using

    End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for replying I tried to make it a public shared function and it still isn't recognizing it. It is a public class aswell.

Comment: I just tested it in vs2010, and its works just fine. What happens when you create an instance of the class and try and use that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class Form1
    Declare Function GetPixel Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetPixel" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
    Declare Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetDesktopWindow" () As Long
    Declare Function GetWindowDC Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowDC" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

    Public Function GetPixelColor(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
        GetPixelColor = GetPixel(GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow), x, y)
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'This is how often the timer refreshes in MILLISECONDS - i.e. 1000 = 1 second
        Timer1.Interval = 2  
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim ScreenX As Integer
        Dim ScreenY As Integer
        Dim bm As Bitmap

        ' ScreenX = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width     Use this code instead, to capture the WHOLE SCREEN
        ' ScreenY = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height    Use this code instead, to capture the WHOLE SCREEN
        'This code captures a CROPPED SECTION OF THE SCREEN - X COORDINATE
        ScreenX = 460
        'This code captures a CROPPED SECTION OF THE SCREEN - X COORDINATE
        ScreenY = 80
        bm = New Bitmap(ScreenX, ScreenY)

        Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
            gr.CopyFromScreen( _
                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, _
                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, _
                0, 0, _
                Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, _
                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
        End Using

        'This is where you tell it WHAT PIXEL to check
        Dim pixelColor As Color = bm.GetPixel(450, 75)  
        PictureBox1.BackColor = pixelColor
        TextBox1.Text = PictureBox1.BackColor.Name
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: open a new project (if you use visual studio i mean) for a forms window application - add 1 textbox (leave the name as the default name, or name it it if you want, but make sure you edit my code above to reflect what you name it) add 1 picturebox (again, same story as before, leave default name, or change it but remember to edit the code also) thats it ! - i have left a parameter commented out so you can pick if you want the bitmap to render the entire screen, and then get a specific pixel from it, or (if thats too processor hungry) leave it as its currently shown above -

Comment: which crops a section of the screen, and then saves it to the bitmap variable - much less to render, and SIGNIFICANT performance increase. i created it, and am running it through a virtual machine with win XP, with 1 core, 2.4ghz, 1GB of virtual RAM, running visual studio 2010 in the background still, (i.e. still having the project openAND running the program, not just the saved/exported .exe file, which would be less for it to think about) AND i had the time interval set to fresh/tick every SINGLE

Comment: millisecond, and task manager barely crept above 4-6% usage . when i did the same test with the full screen, it still was only about 10-12% but would jump to 100% `CPU usage if you were even moving the mouse, or opening other programs etc. 

i hope the above code helps people - you have no idea how much of a nightmare it actually it to get THAT code - specifically THAT code, where you get a pixel from a screen x y coordinate, and NOT from the mouse cursor - and i have found close

Comment: matches, but they sucked your CPU more than  a horny teenage. the above code allows you to pic a certain screen point OR the whole screen, up to up. and it constantly refreshes however regulalry you want it to - i commented where the timer inverval value is